# hostapd_cli chan_switch FAIL

Tags: raspberry-pi, wifi, raspbian, hostapd

I have successfully hosted a WiFi AP using hostapd on my RPi Zero (using an external USB WiFi adapter). I'm using a dual-band adapter and the AP can be initiated in both bands without any problem and also the channel can be changed via the `hostapd.conf` file. However I want to change the channel dynamically and for this other people have successfully used the `hostapd_cli` command `chan_switch` (do a quick Google search).  In my case, I'm always getting the error message "FAIL" like so:

```
> chan_switch 5 5240
> FAIL
```

The exact same result is there no matter what the current band is.  Here is my `hostapd.conf` file.

```
interface=wlan1
driver=nl80211
ssid=test
channel=36
hw_mode=a
ctrl_interface=/var/run/hostapd
ctrl_interface_group=0
```

Any help to get this to work would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You man need to add more arguments to the command.

```
usage: <cs_count> <freq> [sec_channel_offset=] [center_freq1=] [center_freq2=] [bandwidth=] [blocktx] [ht|vht]
```

I see in your configuration that you are configuring the radio to 11ac mode. Hence, you many need to set it to VHT mode.

Try:

```
chan_switch 5 5240 vht
```